# Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:test.tpl'

Tags: php, smarty

I have a `smarty-test02` project, in the `php/test.php` file:

```
<?php

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/smartyHeader.php');
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/test/test01.php');

$msg = 'hello world, this is my first Smarty!';
$title = 'Smarty Title';

$smarty->assign('title', $title);
$smarty->assign('message', $msg);

$movies_arr = array('A'=>'a film', 'B' => 'b file', 'C' => 'c film');

$smarty->assign('movie_arr', $movies_arr);

$smarty->assign('v', ['a', 'b', 'c']);

$extraTemplateVariables = array();

$extraTemplateVariables['test_list'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$extraTemplateVariables['selected_product'] = '';  

$smarty->assign('extraTemplateVariables', $extraTemplateVariables);

$smarty->display('test.tpl');
```

and its template is `templates/test.tpl` :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {*{$title}*}
    </body>
{literal}
    <script lang="javascript">
        function fun(){
            alert('asd');// there I want to alert the $title)
        }
        fun();
    </script>
{/literal}

</html>
```

but when I access the `test.php` by `http://localhost:63342/smarty-test02/php/test.php` I get bellow error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Unable to load template 'file:test.tpl' <-- thrown in /Users/sof/Desktop/TestPHP/smarty-test02/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php on line 187

---

**EDIT-1**

In my smartyHeaders.php:

```
<?php

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libs/Smarty.class.php');

$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->caching = true;
$smarty->cache_lifetime = 120;
$smarty->template_dir = './templates';
$smarty->compile_dir = './templates_c';
```

**EDIT-2**

The directory structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── addon
│   └── test01_addon.php
├── cache
│   └── a521c2377356a0c5c1792bcb5adcde857b3c48e3.test.tpl.php
├── composer.phar
├── libs
│   ├── Autoloader.php
│   ├── Smarty.class.php
│   ├── SmartyBC.class.php
│   ├── bootstrap.php
│   ├── debug.tpl
│   ├── libs\ -\ Verknu�\210pfung.lnk
│   ├── plugins
│   │   ├── block.textformat.php
      ...
│       ├── smarty_variable.php
│       ├── smartycompilerexception.php
│       └── smartyexception.php
├── php
│   └── test.php
├── smartyHeader.php
├── templates
│   ├── child.tpl
│   ├── parent.tpl
│   ├── php
│   │   └── test.tpl
│   ├── test01.tpl
│   └── test02.tpl
├── templates_c
│   ├── 3963a63f17ac1e915beafe6a28decb3ece4b8a7a_0.file.test01.tpl.cache.php
└── test
    └── test01.php
```

Comment: Just wishing to check that [$smarty->setTemplateDir()](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.template.dir.tpl) has been performed on the right path?

Comment: Have you tried setting the template path? `$smarty = new Smarty(); $smarty->setTemplateDir('/web/www.example.com/guestbook/templates/');` From https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.basic.tpl

Comment: @kerbholz See my EIDT-1, if I put the `test.php` to the project root directory and the `test.tpl` to the `templates` directory, there will be come normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute path to template directory:

```
$smarty->template_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templates';
$smarty->compile_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/templates_c';
```

it worked for me (with your scripts)

PHP understood your `./` directory as `test/` directory, because you run `php/test.php` file (and include `smartyHeader.php` in him, but it still `php/` directory - **NOT** root), therefore PHP tried to find `php/templates/test.tpl` file, but the one isn't exist.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 Show your directories please, I'm confused. `/smartyHeader.php` , `/templates/test.tpl`, `/php/test.php` , `/libs/Smarty.class.php` - Is it right?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 I found it - your test.tpl placed in `templates/php/test.tpl`. If you want to include this one, you must use `$smarty->display("php/test.tpl");` OR put file `test.tpl` in `templates` directory (**NOT** `templates/php`)